# Python - Method to convert random points to line?

Tags: python, image

When I have some points its position is random as drawn below. 
[image]

I want to dynamically draw lines with some restrictions.

1) No points in selected region.
2) The triangles are at acute angle.
3) Points are in X/Y (2D) plane.

So points are processed & divided therefore...

[image]

Can I find advice about any appropriate math solutions or even libraries?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum.  Please take the time to read [ask] and the links it contains.

Comment: What exactly is meaning of _"like we were unconscious"_? You can't do anything if unconscious.

Comment: subconscious..? I wanted to describe my subconscious drawing. it's trivial.

Comment: You may want to look up `Delaunay triangulation` & `Voronoi diagram`; you can find implementation of these objects in `scipy.interpolate`

Comment: @ReblochonMasque That's exactly correct!! thank you a lot. Have a nice day.

Comment: Note that your restrictions result in multiple possible valid results. Delaunay triangulation tries to maximize the smallest angle, which (specific cases excluded) leads to a single solution.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque you should add your comment as an answer.

Comment: Yes, I did, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You will want to look up [Delaunay triangulation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Delaunay.html) & [Voronoi diagram](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Voronoi.html); you can find implementation of these objects in scipy.interpolate; I think these constructs are what you are looking for.